# Why can't I ssh into (or even ping) my Ubuntu VM from the Mac OS X host?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machines, ping, vmware-fusion

I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 as a virtual machine using VMware Fusion 3.0 on Mac OS X 10.5.8.  I want to be able to ssh into my VM from the Mac OS X host (so I can use MacFUSE and SSHFS to mount the VM's files on the Mac).

I had this working previously, but then I:

- upgraded Fusion from 2.x to 3.0
- rolled the VM back to a previous snapshot
- upgraded the VMware Tools in the VM

I re-installed ssh in the VM using `sudo apt-get install ssh`.

I then tried `ssh 172.16.193.129` from my Mac, and after some time it timed out.  So I tried pinging the VM from my Mac, and 0 packets were received.  (I can ping the Mac from the VM with no problem.)

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

**Update:** I tried switching from NAT to Bridged (as suggested by [Stephen Thompson](https://serverfault.com/users/25622/stephen-thompson)) and got strange "Time to live exceeded" messages when I tried to ping the VM.  I realized that was due to the VPN I'm using.  I disconnected from the VPN and can now ping the VPN and ssh into it, regardless of whether I use NAT or Bridged.

Comment: All of your network configuration might be a good start.

Comment: womble, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting your network to bridged, so it picks up a network address from your lan, and you will be able to gain access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but is `172.16.193.129` the current IP of the Ubuntu VM?  For testing you should probably drop the firewall (`iptables -F`) if you configured it, as well.

Comment: Yes, I've of course double-checked that I have the right IP.  (Using ifconfig.  Because I'm using NAT in VMware Fusion to share the Mac's network connection, the IP number hasn't changed from when it was working before.)  I didn't configure a firewall, but I ran iptables -F just in case.  I still can't ping the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Steven Thompson's idea worked for me - for whatever reason adding an eth1 (bridged) seemed to fix eth0 (NAT) once I ran `sudo dhclient` (I checked, rebooting didn't fix it by itself, it was only fixed after I ran `sudo dhclient` )